# Inserting selected jTable row into database by clicking a button

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to insert data in my jTable into a database by clicking on a button. I am getting an  exception saying Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sms", "root", "");

        String query="insert into attendance(regNo,name,sClass,attendance,date) values('"+regNo+"','"+names+"','"+sClass+"','"+attendance+"')";
        Statement st=connection.createStatement();

        int row=jTable_Display_Student.getSelectedRow();
        String regNo=(jTable_Display_Student.getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
        String names=(jTable_Display_Student.getValueAt(row, 1).toString());
        String sClass=(jTable_Display_Student.getValueAt(row, 2).toString());
        String attendance=(jTable_Display_Student.getValueAt(row, 3).toString());



        st.executeUpdate(query);

       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Selected Rows Submitted Successfully.");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Any assisantance will be highly appreciated

Comment: This code will not compile. And this code cannot lead to that exception. I guess you are running a different version. And about the problem you posted: what is that exception trying to tell you?

Comment: It is because there are five fields and you are sending only four values in your query

Comment: 5 columns in `regNo,name,sClass,attendance,date`, but only 4 values given in `values('"+regNo+"','"+names+"','"+sClass+"','"+attendance+"')` - missing date...

Comment: but kind of strange: you are creating the SQL command, and after that, loading the values in the variables - Java does not work that way. When it executes the line `String query = ....`, the variable values at that moment are used to created the string. The query variable will not change if the variables are then changed (not to mention that you MUST declare the variables before using... )

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger that's why i said the code will not compile. The variables are used before they are declared.

Comment: @f1sh and that means I cannot repeat it? obviously he could compile and execute it, otherwise it would not throw THAT exception...

Comment: Okay,those four fields i have listed are in the jtable while the date variable is in jdatechooser. I am finding it difficult to insert the data in the jTable into the database by clicking submit button. If there is another way i can do that, i would appreciate the help,code included please

Answer (score 0):

In this part of your code:

```
    String query="insert into attendance(regNo,name,sClass,attendance,date) values('"+regNo+"','"+names+"','"+sClass+"','"+attendance+"')";
```

You have 5 columns

```
 (regNo,name,sClass,attendance,date)
```

and only 4 values to fill them

```
values('"+regNo+"','"+names+"','"+sClass+"','"+attendance+"')
```

So yo need to add the `date` that you are missing

Comment: i matched the columns with the values and now the exception am getting is "Data truntion:Data too long for column 'regNo' at row 1 yet the value in that cell is a one digit number

Answer (score 0):

Use a `PreparedStatement` when attempting to use SQL. The code is easier to read and less error prone.

A basic example to get you started:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Page (Name, Title) VALUES (?, ?)";
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

stmt.setString( 1, nameValue );
stmt.setString( 2, titleValue );
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Hopefully you can new easily tell:

1. the number of columns you are updating and therefore the number of value you need to pass to the SQL statement
2. you don't need to worry about all the delimiters for these values.

Comment: i though i could use preparedStatement but it only works when am entering data from other components like textfield and combobox. How do i specify table colums using preparedStatement

Comment: The same as you do in your code example. You use the getValueAt(...) method of the JTable.